# give an example to show it is possible to remove one vertex and the multiplicity of one of eigenvalue rise.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I know that if we consider a graph $G$ with $\lambda$ as one of its eigenvalue of adjacency matrix with multiplicity $n$ ,there is a  vertex of $G$ that by removing it ,the multiplicity of $\lambda$ will be $n-1$.

now I want to say an example to show that it is possible to remove one vertex and the multiplicity of one of eigenvalue rise,but I couldn't,it will be great if you help me with this,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $C_{3} \cup C_{3} \cup K_{4}$. We have an eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ with multiplicity two. Removing a vertex from $K_{4}$ yields $C_{3}$, thus increasing the multiplicity of $\lambda = 2$ to three.

Comment: thanks,I didn't think this way,if we want to have a connected example,can we have one?

Comment: $C_3$ is 2-regular,and its biggest eigenvalue is 2,so you mean that the multiplicity of $\lambda=2$ increase,am I right?

Comment: That's correct. Serves me right for posting late at night! :-) I can't think of a connected example, but I'm no expert with spectral graph theory. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Comment: thanks a lot,it was so helpful for me,thank you for answering my question.

Comment: The graph on five vertices got by joining a new vertex to one vertex on the the 4-cycle is a connected example. Its eigenvalues are simple and there are three vertices you can delete.